# Regarding distance between sets in metric topology

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space For subsets $A$ and $B$ of $X$, define

$$d(A, B) = \inf\{d(a, b) : a \in A, b \in B\}.$$

Weather the following statement is true or false?

If the intersection of closure of $A$ and closure of $B$ is null set, then
then $d(A, B) > 0$.

Please give counter examples in case the statement is false.

In reals with usual topology and with the usual definition of metric it seems to be true.

Comment: @DietrichBurde yes a null set

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The set $\{(x,y): y\le 0\}$ is closed.

The set $\{(x,y): y\ge 2^x\}$ is closed.

The distance between them is $0$, but they don't intersect.

Answer (score 1):

A counterexample in the reals: $A = \mathbb{N}$, and $B = \{n + \frac{1}{n}: n = 2,3,\ldots \}$ are both closed and discrete, so they have disjoint closures, but $d(A,B) = 0$.

Comment: You mean since intersection of A and B is null set and they are closed and discrete hence they have disjoint closure???

Comment: Indeed, this is what I meant